# Does the iwlwifi Wifi driver for intel cards support AP mode?

Tags: wireless, intel, intel-wireless

Ok from my research so far, there is a driver that intel works on for its newer cards called iwlwifi. there's also iwlagn and I am unsure if they are the same? Anyway, do any of them support AP mode and the cfg80211 architecture?

It seems like the brcm80211 still does not support AP mode so i am looking at alternatives. Atheros is a good option so far :)!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at something called hostapd? It is in the Ubuntu Software Centre with a link to the developer's website. There you will see this comment:

> Note! Host AP driver was added into the main kernel tree in Linux v2.6.14. The version in the kernel tree should be used instead of this external hostap-driver package. The external releases are only for older kernel versions and all the future development will be in the main kernel tree.

I have also found this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode

Regards.

Comment: I want to use hostapd. I already use it right now, i just wanted to know if i can still use it with the Intel Wifi cards. With Atheros and some broadcom chips, its a breeze to get a hostapd installation working. But it is dependent on driver support, and hence the reason for my question. I dug around a bit and saw that, the iwlwifi driver does not have AP mode enabled...